# Code coverage concern on promise/asynchronous unit testing using nockjs and jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, code-coverage, nock

I have written a simple unit test for API call using NockJS and Jest for a react application as bellow:

AjaxService.js

```
export const AjaxService = {
    post: (url, data, headers) => {
        return axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: url,
            headers: headers || { "content-type": "application/json" },
            data: data
        });
    },
};
```

API Promise:

```
export const getDashboard = (request) => {
  return AjaxService.post(API_DASHBOARD_URL + "/getDashboard", request
  ).then(
    response => {
      return response.data;
    },
    (error) => {
      return error.response.data;
    }
  )
};
```

Unit test using NockJS:

```
nock(baseUrl)
    .post(subUrl, request)
    .reply(200, response);

getDashboard(request)
    .then(resp => {
        let compareVal = getNestedObject(resp, keyToCompare);
        let actualVal = getNestedObject(response, keyToCompare);
        expect(compareVal).to.equal(actualVal);
    })
    .then(() => {});
```

But when the code-coverage report is generated using Jest `--coverage` as below:

[image]

We can see that in promise, **success callback** and **error callback** is **not** called during unit test. How to cover this part of code as it affects code-coverage percentage when an application is having numerous API calls? Or am I not testing is properly? Please help as I am new to unit testing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm, the `baseUrl` value being passed to nock is the same `API_DASHBOARD_URL` correct? I want to make sure you're mocking the outbound request from your app and not the inbound request to the app.

Comment: Yes!. BaseUrl and API_DASHBOARD_URL is the same.

Comment: What is `AjaxService`? Have you tried messing with the contents of your success callback to see if the test still passes?

Comment: AjaxService will return axios instance. And no I have not tried to change any contents of callbacks. I have updated question. Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Jest` counts a line as covered only if it runs *during a test*.

In this case it looks like you are calling `getDashboard` during the test...

...but `getDashboard` is asynchronous and the test isn't waiting for it to finish.

This means that the test completes synchronously before the asynchronous code in `getDashboard` has a chance to run and any code that hasn't run yet is not included in the `Jest` code coverage.

To make sure that code is properly tested and included in the code coverage make sure you `await` the `Promise` returned by `getDashboard`:

```
test('getDashboard', async () => {  // <= async test function
  nock(baseUrl)
    .post(subUrl, request)
    .reply(200, response);

  await getDashboard(request)  // <= await the Promise
    .then(resp => {
      let compareVal = getNestedObject(resp, keyToCompare);
      let actualVal = getNestedObject(response, keyToCompare);
      expect(compareVal).to.equal(actualVal);
    })
})
```

Comment: Or you can `return` (instead of `await`) the `Promise` in the `test`, in case the callback is not written as `async`. See [this example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store#asynchronous-actions)