# Test an API call in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test the API call in my React component and also tried few ways by surfing the net.

**MyComponent:**

```
    export const API = {
      getData() {
        return fetch(localStorage.blobUrl).then(res => res.blob())
      }
    }

    const downloadArchiveFile = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('blobUrl',bloburl);
    API.getData().then((blob) => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.style.display = "none";
      a.href = url;
      // the filename you want
      a.download = templateName;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
  };
```

**MyComponent.test.js**

```
it('api call', async () => {
        const fakeUserResponse = {
            'myResponse': {
                'a': '1',
                'b': '2' }
        };
        var apiFunc = jest.spyOn(API, 'getData').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return Promise.resolve({
                json: () => Promise.resolve(fakeUserResponse)
            })
        })
    })
```

**Test case is getting passed. But while seeing code coverage this code is not covered.**

See the code coverage report

[image]

**Links which I refer:**

[React - how do I unit test an API call in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576450/react-how-do-i-unit-test-an-api-call-in-jest)

[Code coverage concern on promise/asynchronous unit testing using nockjs and jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656523/code-coverage-concern-on-promise-asynchronous-unit-testing-using-nockjs-and-jest)

Comment: Which library do you use to test the react component? `react-testing-library` or `enzyme`?

Comment: I used enzyme library